# Self-contained proof of $\chi^2$ test for independence in two-way tables?

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference

How can I derive the asymptotic distribution of the $\chi^2$ statistic for independence in two-way tables?

For those who are unfamiliar, here is the setup of the problem. We classify $n$ individuals in terms of two categorical variables $A=\{a_1,\dotsc, a_I\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\dotsc,b_J\}$. We can arrange the data in a table 
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}
& b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_J &\text{total}\\ \hline
a_1 & n_{11}& n_{12}&\cdots &n_{1J}&R_1\\ \hline
\vdots & \vdots & & &\vdots&\vdots\\ \hline
a_I & n_{I1} & n_{I2}& & n_{IJ}&R_I\\ \hline
\text{total} & C_1 & C_2& \cdots & C_J & n\\ \hline
\end{array}
where $n_{ij}$ counts the number of individuals classified as $a_i$ and $b_j$, $R_i$ and $C_j$ are the row $i$ and column $j$ totals, respectively, and $n=\sum_{i,j}n_{ij}$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then we expect to see $E_{ij} = R_i C_j/n$ individuals in cell $(i,j)$. Pearson's $\chi^2$ statistic is defined as
\begin{align*}
X^2=\sum_{i,j}\frac{(n_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}}.
\end{align*}
If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $X^2\overset{d}{\to}\chi^2_{(I-1)(J-1)}$ as $n\to\infty$.

I would like to know how to explicitly calculate this asymptotic distribution. I understand how to derive the asymptotic distribution of Pearson's $\chi^2$ statistic for goodness-of-fit, but this appears significantly more complicated because of the multiple factors and the constant row/column sums, and I'm not quite sure where to begin.

Comment: Since the row and column sums are not constrained (only the total), would the number of degrees of freedom be I*J-1?

Comment: @Dean The row and column sums are constrained. I should have made that clearer. The reasoning is that we happened to have observed the column and row totals. Then, if the factors are unrelated, if we observed $R_i$ individuals in group $a_i$, we expect the proportion $C_j/n$ of them to be in group $b_j$, giving the expected proportion $E_{ij}=R_iC_j/n$.

Comment: I thiks that this fact follows from the limiting distribution of statistic for chi-square test when testing distribution depends on a number of unknown parameters. Here we have $(J-1)+(I-1)$ unknown parameters (probabilities of each group),  and the number of degrees of freedom of limiting distribution should be $IJ-1-((J-1)+(I-1))=(I-1)(J-1)$. I doubt that this result admits more simple proof than the general result of Fisher. See various proofs here: http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2014/ams-133-136-2014/buonocoreAMS133-136-2014.pdf

Comment: @NCh This is slightly different from the result stated there because E_i,j is not the theorical probability but rather the probability estimated from the constraints

Comment: @Sergio If $E_{i,j}$ were theoretical probabilities, the question would not have arisen. In this case, the limiting distribution would have $IJ-1$ degrees of freedom. Of course, these are estimates for probabilities. And exactly in this case there is $(I-1)(J-1)$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: @NCh I understand that the rows and columns as constraints have the effect of reducing degrees of freedom. But what effect does using them as estimators for the actual probabilities have ? The paper you linked actually mentions this issue